# $.connection.hub.id is undefined in done function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

We're using SignalR 1.2.1. Here is my start function:

```
$.connection.hub.start(self._SignalROptions)
            .done(function () {
                self._connecting = false;
                log("Connected to dashboard hub successfully. (id=" + $.connection.hub.id + ")");
                self._ensureExistingClientFunctionsAreRegistered();
                if (aDoneFunction) {
                    aDoneFunction();
                }
            })
            .fail(function () {
                log("Connection to dashboard hub failed!");
            });
```

Occasionally (seems like a timing thing) we get a console log:

**Connected to dashboard hub successfully. (id=undefined)**

Then any future functions called on the hub throw the exception

**"Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()"**

David Fowl says in the following article that $connection.hub.id cannot be undefined in the done function yet it's definitely happening: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/557

What am I doing wrong? If this is fixed in a future version we're upgrading soon but can someone provide evidence for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have at least one hub method configured on the client. Next try removing your self._SignalROptions to make sure there isn't something here and allow it to use the default transport, etc. I would remove all code in your done method other than the log statement, which I would switch to an alert to rule out any parsing issue.

Enable logging and view the console to make sure there are no errors getting raised.

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true
```

Lastly, put a breakpoint on the server and see if the OnConnected method is getting hit in the hub. If you are still not getting a connection id, I would file an issue on GitHub for the SignalR team.

You should be getting an id back and if you have removed all your customized code, there is not much else to do here. There is always a possibility that your server code has an issue as well.